# For singular cohomology, $f^* f_* = $ the norm?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X, Y$ be compact Riemann surfaces, and $f : X \to Y$ a non-constant morpshim, such that the field extension $\mathbb{C}(X)/ \mathbb{C}(Y)$ is Galois.
Then using Poincare duality, we can define the push forward $f_* : H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(Y, \mathbb{Z})$.
Then for any $\alpha \in H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$, $f^* f_* \alpha = \Sigma \sigma \alpha$, where $\sigma$ varies over $\operatorname{Gal}(X/Y)$?

I have search many text and web pages, but I couldn't find it.

For example, Hatcher's Algebraic Topology does not use even the push forward of cohomology.

Comment: There is something called the Becker-Gottlieb transfer that is defined in great generality that I suspect in this situation coincides with your push forward. The Becker-Gottlieb transfer has the composition you ask about equal to multiplication by the Euler characteristic of the (homotopy) fiber. Perhaps someone knows if these coincide in this case.

Comment: What is $Aut(X/Y)$?

Comment: Have you looked in Otto Forster's *Riemann Surfaces*? The first chapter introduces gadgets called "factors of automorphy" which arise when you do this on the level of differential forms.